# Footer not positioning properly

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

My footer is stuck at the bottom of my page, I have removed all calls to bottom and clear that I can find that I think would affect it. I am trying to have my footer sit under the divs in the page and display inline. Currently, I have them displaying inline, but the footer refuses to sit under the rest of the divs. Instead, it sits further down the page.

I am including paste bins to my code.

HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw/mFnTvvte

CSS: http://pastebin.com/raw/Ja5gAMcj

Please help me I have been unable to get it to move up the page for a while.

Comment: use <li> tag for menu

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean the top set of divs?

Comment: What do you expect people to do with the code you posted? Set up an example of your code somewhere like jsfiddle.net .

Comment: ok I will thank you